# Changing text's size according to TextView

Tags: android, text, textview

Hi guys I've wondered if I could resize the TextView's text in order to make it fit withing the text view.
I want the text view to have a default text size, but in case the text is too long and requires more text than the TextView could offer, the text size should get smaller.

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782522/3137842) which is awesome, but it's also from 2013, so I've wondered if there's a simpler way of doing this. Android keeps changing and evolving so I just wanted to make sure there's no easier solution first.

Comment: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview check this

Comment: Agreed -- I would use an existing library, like https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView or https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView or the one Ravi mentioned.

Comment: Thanks guys, seems there's no other choice ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way of achieving this in Android, so you'll have to resort to 3rd party classes and libraries to fix your problem (Like the one you linked)

I have tried a few different classes i found from googling around about 6 months ago, but i never found a 100% working solution, there were always some little kinks or flaws in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) for better result .

> A TextView that automatically fit its font and line count based on its
>   available size and content.